# Подсчёт значений в нескольких инпута

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть конструкция:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <button>-</button>
    <input type="number">
    <button>+</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>-</button>
    <input type="number">
    <button>+</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>-</button>
    <input type="number">
    <button>+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

По нажатию на кнопку я повесил событие `change` для инпута. Теперь хочу по событию `change` запускать функцию, которая будет считать и суммировать числа из каждого инпута. Например, если в первом инпуте 3, во втором 5, а в третьем 8, то результатом выполнения функции будет вывод числа 16. Как можно реализовать подсчёт не обращаясь к классам и `:nth`-селекторам?

Comment: Выложите JS-код.

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = 0.0;
$("input[type='number']").each(function(){
    res += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Решил свой вопрос:

```
$(function(){
  var input = $('.passengers-list').find('.numeric-input');
  var passengers;
  input.on('change', function(){
    passengers = 0;
    $(input).each(function(){
      passengers += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    updatePassengers(passengers)
  });
});
```

В ответе пользователя @Міша счётчик только прибавлял и если была нажата кнопка "минус", которая уменьшала значение в соседнем инпуте, то общее значение всё равно бы увеличилось. Из-за чего глобальное значение всегда нужно обнулять.